# Why does LINQ to Entities not support SingleOrDefault()?

Tags: linq-to-entities

Any ideas why LINQ to Entities doesn't support `SingleOrDefault()` but instead ask to use `FirstOrDefault()`?

Will `SingleOrDefault()` functionality be replaced? By what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why it was left out, but you can always roll your own.

I found a similar response to this question on MSDN, here is an implementation based off of that code.

```
public static TElement SingleOrDefault<TElement>
      (this IQueryable<TElement> query)
{
    if (query.Count() == 1)
        return query.First();
    else if (query.Count() == 0)
        return null;
    else
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
}


// Use it like this

Product prod = (from p in db.Product
                where p.ProductID == 711
                select p).SingleOrDefault();
```

[Source: MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/afb292ca-3a61-4a60-8e18-830b92489016)

Comment: I didn't see the code you provided in that link. The implementation you've shown appears to be exactly like FirstOrDefault() - at least from my memory. SingleOrDefault() would return null if there are no results, return a single result if only one exists, or throw an exception if there is more than one result.

Comment: Actually, SingleOrDefault throws when there is more than one result found.  That's the point of it--zero or one record must be returned; otherwise an error has occurred.  From the docs:  "this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence."  Your version isn't correct.